# Can rsync copy files without data?

Tags: rsync

Is there a way for rsync to copy a set of files without copying their data, much in the same way that `cp --attributes-only` does?

I'm asking because I'd like "preview" metadata about a set files that were previously backed up with rsync using archive (`-a`) and fake-super (`-M--fake-super`) modes (which stored metadata and true owners in extended attributes), without needing to take the time or space to copy the file contents back before examining their metadata and true owners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally `rsync` relies on timestamps and file-sizes when copying to a remote site, but compares file contents for local files.  You can modify this behavior using `--ignore-times` and `--ignore-size`.

If you repeat the `-v` (verbose) option, it adds details on the files which are copied.  To *preview*, use the `-n` (no-op or "dry-run") option.

Repeating `-v` 4 times shows the meta data (for Debian, using rsync 3.0.9-4).

Here's a part of the output from a dry-run:

```
[sender] make_file(imsg.c,*,2)
[sender] make_file(vis.h,*,2)
[sender] make_file(fgetln.c,*,2)
[sender] make_file(fparseln.c,*,2)
[sender] make_file(openat.c,*,2)
[sender] flist start=1, used=28, low=0, high=27
[sender] i=1 /tmp/tmux-2.1/compat ./ mode=040755 len=4096 uid=1001 gid=100 flags=5
[sender] i=2 /tmp/tmux-2.1/compat asprintf.c mode=0100644 len=1465 uid=1001 gid=100 flags=0
[sender] i=3 /tmp/tmux-2.1/compat b64_ntop.c mode=0100644 len=7418 uid=1001 gid=100 flags=0
```

The first part of that is shown at 3 `-v` options.